# Outputting sql queries to file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, output

I have 5 queries that need to be outputted to a fixed length file.  Security is not a concern so if I need to open something up for a simpler solution that's completely okay.

So just to simplify let's say I had these two queries:

```
Select 'Walmart   ' Company, '123  ' StoreNo, '456   ' InvoiceNo
Select '00000234958328' UPC, '00023' Quantity
```

And I want the results to be output into a fixed length file like so:

```
Walmart   123  456   
0000023495832800023
```

I obviously can't union the queries together since they have different columns, so I imagine I would need to be able to append to the file rather than only being able to overwrite it.  Is there a way to do this that can be automated and doesn't require me to use tools outside of sql server?

Comment: Why can't you just run the queries separately? gather up the data, THEN write the file.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: how about: http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/7080/export-results-of-a-query-into-a-csvtxt-file.html

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks, forgot to do that.

Comment: @MarcB I can run them separate, but I was just saying that in order to do that I need to make sure I output to the file in a way that doesn't override it each time.

Comment: @cpoDesign Thanks, at this point I'm thinking bcp might be my best option except there's no option to append.  But I just got an idea from here that might work: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/9a1b5669-63bb-4d27-9154-443b69363e52/

Comment: @MarcB Oh, I just re-read your comment and I'm not quite sure what you mean.  When you say 'gather up the data', what do you have in mind?

Comment: There is no way to write to a file outside SQL Server without using an external tool. Even 'pure' TSQL solutions usually call bcp.exe using `xp_cmdshell` or do some other awkward workaround with `echo`. So since you have to use an external tool anyway, why not write a small script to do this; TSQL is a very poor language for text manipulation and formatting so it would be much easier. And of course bcp.exe and sqlcmd.exe are part of SQL Server and can write to files.

Answer (score 0):

how about a simple hack...

```
Select 'Walmart   ' , '123  ' , '456   '  from dual
union
Select '00000234958328' , '00023' , null from dual;
```

or really - since you want one fixed length string per row, just concatenate them all similar to this:

```
Select company || storeno || invoiceno  from dual
union
Select upc || qty from dual;
```

you'll probably want to play with RPAD or some formatting depending on your DBMS

Comment: Sorry, forgot to label this as mssql.  Not that I couldn't do the equivalent in mssql, but I'm more interested in how I might append the results of each query to a file than to hack them into a single query if possible.